# CSS3 Opacity transition, chrome not fading background-image

Tags: jquery, macos, google-chrome, safari, css-transitions

I'm working on my portfolio and i'm trying some parallax effects with a fade-in on view.

I prefer CSS3 transitions for the animation I only used Jquery waypoints to trigger it.

The fade in works fine in Firefox the whole div fades in however in Chrome & Safari on Mac the background-image of the div does not fade it just jumps in.

for an example check (the blurry part should fade in)
http://www.jasperaarts.com/2013/#work

I add or remove a class active_item or inactive_item this way I trigger the CSS transition.

```
.active_item {

    -webkit-opacity: 1.0;
    -moz-opacity: 1.0;
    -ms-opacity: 1.0;
    -o-opacity: 1.0;
    opacity: 1.0;

    -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms ease 500ms;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1000ms ease 500ms;
    -ms-transition: opacity 1000ms ease 500ms;
    -o-transition: opacity 1000ms ease 500ms;
    transition: opacity 1000ms ease 500ms;
}
.inactive_item {

    -webkit-opacity: 0;
    -moz-opacity: 0;
    -ms-opacity: 0;
    -o-opacity: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Alternatives I have tried are Jquery fadeIn and fadeOut or Animate css in Jquery both show simliar results.

Comment: Strange, this doesn't seem to be an issue with transitions, but opacity and the background-attachment property. You'll notice that even if you remove the transition and set the opacity to `0.9` the background image doesn't show, but if remove the `background-attachment: fixed` property it works fine.

Comment: Thanks you pointed me in the right direction, but I do need the background-attachement: fixed; for the parallax effect for the dynamically repositioning of the background to work.

Comment: Is there a legit reason why Chrome & Safari does not support fading background-images when using background-attachment: fixed? Or is this a browser bug because in Firefox the code works perfectly.

Comment: Looks like this is a bug, probably with web-kit. When I try to reproduce it on another page I can't but nonetheless when I remove that property from your page it fixes that issue. I tried for a while but couldn't narrow it down further. I would suggest trying to narrow it down by removing everything from the page and building up to the point where this breaks, if its a bug report it to the web-kit team. If all else fails you should be able to use an absolute positioned image.

Comment: I thought I tried everything until I disabled the Isotop.js script the fade works again. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Godwin, I have narrowed it down to a compatibility issue with Isotope.js script and the Parallax css.